# Use python-docx module to get table content in word, error reported

Tags: python-docx

Use python-docx module to get table content in word, error reported

```
    mydocumnet = docx.Document(doc_Path)
    mytable = mydocumnet.tables[0]
    print("表格行数", len(mytable.rows))
    for myRow in mytable.rows:
        print(type(myRow))
        for cell in myRow.cells:
            print(cell.text)
    mydocumnet.save(doc_Path)
```

The error information is as follows：

```
F:\Python3.11.3\python.exe E:\pythonProject1\main.py 
Hi, PyCharm
表格行数 5
<class 'docx.table._Row'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\pythonProject1\main.py", line 21, in <module>
    for cell in myRow.cells:
                ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python3.11.3\Lib\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 401, in cells
    return tuple(self.table.row_cells(self._index))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python3.11.3\Lib\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 103, in row_cells
    column_count = self._column_count
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python3.11.3\Lib\site-packages\docx\table.py", line 185, in _column_count
    return self._tbl.col_count
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python3.11.3\Lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\table.py", line 140, in col_count
    return len(self.tblGrid.gridCol_lst)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "F:\Python3.11.3\Lib\site-packages\docx\oxml\xmlchemy.py", line 513, in get_child_element
    raise InvalidXmlError(
docx.oxml.exceptions.InvalidXmlError: required ``<w:tblGrid>`` child element not present

进程已结束,退出代码1
```

Reinstall python and the module Python-docx
word table contents can be read using the python-docx module